# csvwriter writing in a loop issue

Tags: python-3.x, csv

try to write to multiple row and can't seem to do it with this code:

```
i = range(1, 21)

page_number = 38050
#rownumber = 0
for element in i:
    url = 'https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=' + format(page_number)

    response = get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    page_number += 1


    game_length = html_soup.select('div.game_times li div')[-1].string
    game_developer = html_soup.find_all('strong')[1].next_sibling.string
    game_publisher = html_soup.find_all('strong')[2].next_sibling.string
    game_console = html_soup.find_all('strong')[3].next_sibling.string
    game_genres = html_soup.find_all('strong')[4].next_sibling.string

    print(url)
    print(game_name)
    print(game_length)
    print(game_developer)
    print(game_publisher)
    print(game_genres)
    print(game_console)

    with open('HLTB.csv', 'w') as f: 
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
#         thewriter.writerow(['Game Name:', 'Game Length:', 'Game Developer:', "Game Publisher:", 'Game Genre:', 'Game Console']) 
        row = [game_name, game_length, game_developer, game_publisher, game_genres, game_console]
        thewriter.writerow(row)

  #  rownumber += 1
```

just worried about the CSV part for now but it only writes the last entry (writing over the previous one)

what am I doing wrong?

how can I make it so there is a new row per game?

I have a feeling it's to do with a varialbe I can add but not sure where (hence why I have the rownumber varibale listed)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems

1. You are reopening the file in loop and rewriting use `a` instead of `w`. This will overwrite your previous content. See

`for element in i:
   # ...
   # ---> Wrong way of writing
   with open('HLTB.csv', 'w') as f:
       ...`

2. You can move `with open('HLTB.csv', 'w') as f:` out of loop and then it will not overwrite.